# Android download progress notification layout not found?

Tags: android, notifications

I need to display the download progress in the notification area (like the Market does). I found several examples, all of them using the XML layout android.R.layout.download_progress. All the examples look great and simple to implement. The issue is, android.R.layout.download_progress does not seem to exist! It will not show up in Eclipse's intellisense, it won't compile, and even the official Android documentation (sorry, can't provide a link because I'm a new member) does not have this field. So why does it show up in multiple examples online? Am I missing something? I'd really prefer to not have to reinvent the wheel here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `android.R.layout.download_progress` is a public but undocumented part of the platform. Try to avoid using it; see below for an example ProgressBar you can put in your custom Notification RemoteViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really reinventing the wheel. It's a really simple declaration.

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currentlyplaying_songimage"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:max="100"/>
```

Now just, instead, use `R.layout.progress_file_name`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not much help to you since you most likely want to run on older phones too, but there's a new API in ICS that makes this super easy: [`Notification.Builder.setProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setProgress%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29).